# Show that the sample covariance converges in probability to the $Cov(X,Y)$

Tags: self-study, covariance, convergence, joint-distribution

Suppose we are given $[(Y_i,X_i)]^{n}_{i=1}$ which is a random sample from the joint distribution of $(Y,X).

Show that the sample covariance converges in probability to the $Cov(X,Y)$

My thought process: I suppose all I need to show is that as $n$, the sample size, approaches infinity, the sample covariance is a reliable estimator of the covariance, right?

Looking at the sample covariance, it is clear that the divisor, $(n-1)$, gets larger and larger as $n$ approaches infinity making the covariance smaller and smaller near the true value. And due to the Sample Analogue Principle, the sample covariance is a reliable estimator as well.

However, this isn't very rigorous. Is there a better way of going about this question?

Many thanks!

Comment: The sample covariance is a U-statistic. Alternatively, you can use Chebyshew's inequality to show that an unbiased estimator with asymptotically vanishing variance is consistent (i.e. converges in probability to the target parameter). Writing down the variance, you'll see your argument about $n-1$ in a rigorous way.

Comment: I understand what a U-Stat is but I am not familiar with Chebyshew's inequality, or at least we were not taught it in my class. Is there an alternative method? Many thanks.

Comment: Anyone? I'm still stuck on this problem :/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let us write the sample covariance in the following way (this is rather standard decomposition):
$$
\frac{n}{n-1}\left(\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}X_iY_i-\bar{X}_n\bar{Y}_n \right)
$$
Now, the first term inside the brackets converges in probability to $E(XY)$ by the weak law of large numbers. Similarly, each of the means converges in probability to the appropriate expectation. Recalling that $Cov(X,Y)=E(XY)-E(X)E(Y)$ we are done since $\frac{n-1}{n}$ converges to $1$. If you want to prove it formally, you should use Slutsky's theorem (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slutsky%27s_theorem)

Note that here we have convergence in probability, but since the convergence is to a constant, it's the same as convergence in distribution.