# Does a larger sample size mean that the sample covariance matrix will converge to the underlying covariance matrix?

Tags: covariance-matrix

Suppose I have a random vector $\boldsymbol{X}\sim N(\boldsymbol{\mu},\boldsymbol{\Sigma})$ where $\boldsymbol{X},\boldsymbol{\mu}\in\mathbb{R}^p$ and $\boldsymbol{\Sigma} \in \mathbb{R}^{p\times p}$.

Suppose we take $n$ draws from this distribution giving us $\boldsymbol{x}_1, \boldsymbol{x}_2,...,\boldsymbol{x}_n$, where each $x_i \in \mathbb{R}^p$. Then my sample mean is

$$\bar{\boldsymbol{x}} = \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^{n} \boldsymbol{x}_i$$

and my sample covariance matrix is

$$\boldsymbol{S}_n =\frac{1}{n-1} \sum_{i=1}^{n} (\boldsymbol{x}_i-\bar{\boldsymbol{x}})(\boldsymbol{x}_i-\bar{\boldsymbol{x}})^T$$

Will $\boldsymbol{S}_n$ eventually converge to $\boldsymbol{\Sigma}$?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The sample covariance matrix is [consistent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Consistent_estimator) (i.e. $S_n$ converges to $\Sigma$ in probability), see for example [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3095171/showing-that-an-estimator-for-covariance-is-consistent) or [this post](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/134910/show-that-the-sample-covariance-converges-in-probability-to-the-covx-y), which describe how every entry of $S_n$ will converge in probability to the corresponding entry in $\Sigma$. (As $n \to \infty$ the difference between the scaling factor $\frac{1}{n-1}$ and $\frac{1}{n}$ is immaterial.)

---

If pointwise convergence is not your intention, there are many other results for other modes of convergence, e.g. here are some notes on [convergence in the operator norm](http://www.stat.cmu.edu/%7Earinaldo/Teaching/36755/F17/Scribed_Lectures/F17_0925.pdf) in the Gaussian case. This is a pretty broad research area, with many different results with various assumptions (asymptotic results, non-asymptotic results, Gaussian assumption or relaxing to some sub-Gaussian distributional assumption, special cases of sparse covariance matrices, etc.).

Comment: It looks like the results you have linked apply for univariate cases, but I have a niggling feeling that the situation involving a multivariate sample covariance matrix converging in probability to the population covariance matrix is not quite as simple as a series of univariate pointwise convergence statements on every element of the matrices. However, I'm unsure and am keen to know more.

Comment: @microhaus Since you haven't specified what mode of convergence you are interested in, your question is then quite broad. I've added some notes to my answer, but it might be good to ask a separate question once you narrow down your search.

Comment: I did not post the question, but am curious to hear about the answer.

Comment: @microhaus Oops, apologies for the misunderstanding. If you search for "covariance matrix estimation" you will find a wide variety of results on this. For non-asymptotic results, Chapter 6 of [Wainwright's book](https://www.cambridge.org/core/books/highdimensional-statistics/8A91ECEEC38F46DAB53E9FF8757C7A4E) is pretty comprehensive. There are probably good references for asymptotic results, but maybe someone more knowledgeable can provide pointers.

Comment: Thank you for supplying the references, I remain curious about this because after consulting the standard statistical texts I couldn't find anything about the consistency of the sample covariance matrix as an estimator. I suppose my first comment amounts to raising a concern about whether:

$$\{\forall i,j = 1, \dots, p \space; (\mathbf{S_n})_{ij} \overset{p}{\rightarrow} \boldsymbol{\Sigma}_{ij} \} \implies \{ \mathbf{S_n} \overset{p}{\rightarrow} \boldsymbol{\Sigma} \} \quad ???$$

Comment: @microhaus You need to define what $S_n \overset{p}{\to} \Sigma$ means for matrices. Typically it is $d(S_n , \Sigma) \to 0$ for some real-valued measure of distance $d$, but you need to specify $d$. The notes on the operator norm I linked in an earlier comment use the operator norm for $d$; one might also consider the Frobenius norm instead. Pointwise convergence corresponds to $d$ being $d(S_n, \Sigma) = \max_{i,j} |(S_n)_{ij}-\Sigma_{ij}|$. Each choice of $d$ will lead to a different notion of convergence. Convergence w.r.t. one $d$ may imply convergence in another choice of $d$, etc.